# Scala Array Type Mismatch

Tags: arrays, scala, casting

I am fairly new to scala and don't fully understand the typecasting. But I have a library method like this:

```
def getSecurityToken(
    endpointUrl:String ,
    stsEndpoint:String ,
    certificateChain:Array[Certificate] ,
    privateKey:PrivateKey
  )
  :SecurityToken
```

Which I am trying to call.. but the result of my `.getCertificateChain` returns an `Array[509Certificate]`

So getSecurityToken spits this error:

```
[error]  found   : Array[java.security.cert.X509Certificate]
[error]  required: Array[java.security.cert.Certificate]
[error] Note: java.security.cert.X509Certificate <: java.security.cert.Certificate, but class Array is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: java.security.cert.Certificate`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]         security.getSecurityToken(DefaultConstants.CORE_ENDPOINT, DefaultConstants.STS_ENDPOINT, certificateChain, privateKey);
```

I tried changing the array as it suggests with `var certificateChain: Array[_ <: Certificate]` (Which is returned by my getCertificateChain) but that gives me this:

```
[error]  found   : Array[_$1] where type _$1 <: java.security.cert.Certificate
```

Can someone please explain how to get through using an array of children objects to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala array is invariant, as it's just a wrapper over Java mutable array.

If you can't change method signatures, you have to create an array of the needed type (which is `Array[Certificate]`, not `Array[_ <: Certificate`])

For that just use `toArray` method.

```
getSecurityToken("something", "something", certificateChain.toArray, privateKey)
```

Comment: `.toArray` is not a cast. That would be `certificateChain.asInstanceOf[Array[Certificate]]`, which will fail.

Comment: You are right, misguiding choice of words. Edited .

Answer (score 1):

I think [Type Ascription](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html) may be enough to solve your problem.

Just simplify your case with the following code.

```
class XX
class XXX extends XX

// an up-cast on Array(new XXX, new XXX)
val a1: Array[XX] = Array(new XXX, new XXX)
def func(x: Array[XX]) = x

// res0: Array[XX] = Array(XXX@7a1234bf, XXX@2f62ea70)
func(a1)
```

In your case, it would be like this:

```
// 509Certificate <: Certificate
val a1: Array[Certificate] = Array[509Certificate]
```

then your can pass a1 to getSecurityToken.

Comment: So I tried this:           `val cc: Array[X509Certificate] = credential.getCertificateChain()` followed by
         `val certificateChain: Array[Certificate] = cc` but it still gave me the same error?